# Delay lines of subtitles by 0.04 seconds more than the line before

Tags: subtitle

I used `aegisub` to synchronize the subtitles of a 1 hour video.
It looks perfect inside `aegisub`, but when I open the `file.ass` with another player there is a gradual delay...
It is up to 23 seconds at the end of the video!

I did the math and each lines are ~0.04 sec delayed. (The first 0.04, the second 0.08, etc...)

Is there a way to automatically change the timing using what I know ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if aegis can fix this, but I fixed it with `Gaupol` : Tool, Transform position and i subtracted the delay on the last line.